# css transform rotate and skew not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

I am trying to make a grid of hexagons using rotate and skew from webkit-transform. It works great in chrome on my laptop but it does not work in safari or when I look at the site using the chrome app on my phone.

Here is the css and Html try with the snippet

```css
.hexIn-1 {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #252839;
 color: #ffffff;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg) rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg) rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg) rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform: skew(0deg, -30deg) rotate(60deg);
 transform: skew(0deg, -30deg) rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
 -ms-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
 -moz-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
 -o-transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
 transition: all 0.35s ease-in;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="hexIn-1" href="/site/laefleif/about" target="_self">
  <h1> about </h1>
</a>
```

here is what it looks like in chrome on my computer:
[image]

and here it is in safari on my computer:
[image]

I have looked extensively on here for the answer but all the things I have found did not work. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `position` property to `relative` or any other than static on the element with `overflow: hidden`.